# Enforcing compatibility with Swift 5.2 in Xcode 12

Tags: swift, xcode

Is there a way to enforce compatibility with Swift 5.2 in Xcode 12 so that I cannot accidentally introduce code that doesn't compile with Swift 5.2 anymore?

I'd like to use Xcode 12 Beta for working on a iOS 13 app because of the vastly improved error messages for SwiftUI and much better auto completion. But I need to keep the project fully compatible with Swift 5.2 for actually building the product using Xcode 11.

There are features like [Allow implicit self in escaping closures when self is explicitly captured](https://forums.swift.org/t/allow-implicit-self-in-escaping-closures-when-self-is-explicitly-captured/22590) in Swift 5.3 that will not compile with Swift 5.2, for example:

```
class SomeViewController : UIViewController {

    func bar() {       
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) { [self] in
            foo()
        }
    }
    
    func foo() {
    }

}
```

The `SWIFT_VERSION` build setting only allows to specify a major version but not something like '5.2'.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the code in an `#if compiler` block. For example:

```swift
func bar() {       
  UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) { [self] in
     #if compiler(>=5.3)
       foo()
     #else
       self.foo()
     #endif
  }
}
```

For the above scenario, this is probably overkill and it would be better to simply not rely on [SE-0269](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0269-implicit-self-explicit-capture.md):

```swift
func bar() {       
  UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) {
    self.foo()
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can download an older toolchain from [swift.org](https://swift.org/download/) and use that instead. However, keep in mind that you won't be able to submit apps to the App Store using a non-default toolchain.

So, I think the best course of action here is to either not use features that depend on a newer compiler or install Xcode 11 side-by-side to develop the iOS 13 app.

Comment: That's not what I meant - I don't want to make this code compile in both Xcode versions but limit Xcode 12 to the feature set of Swift 5.2 (and show the same error as Xcode 11) so that I cannot accedentially introduce code that doesn't compile with Swift 5.2 anymore.

Comment: As I mentioned above, you can download an older toolchain from swift.org. For example, you can download the Swift 5.2.4 toolchain and use that with Xcode 12. However, you won’t be able to submit an app compiled with that toolchain i.e. you’ll have to switch back to the default toolchain before uploading the app. Anyhow, if you switch the toolchain to an older version, you’ll also lose many of the features you mentioned above, like improved SwiftUI errors and fast auto-completion because they depend on a newer compiler, not on a newer IDE.